# How can I do inline function calls in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I want to call functions inline in Objective-C. How can I do this? I'm on iOS.

Comment: Yeah, this is very poorly explained. Provide examples from other languages if you want to learn how to do it in Objective C. You gotta give us some info if you want info in return!

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to answer the question. Maybe if you tell us why you think you need "to call function by inline" we can help you.

Comment: Inline functions are functions where the call is made to inline functions. The actual code then gets placed in the calling program.  ....what more information i give u in this .i want example for this. ...what u want more in this ????????? @daniel t. if u dont know abt this then dont give ans.y u r dong downvote ????

Comment: this is recursion: "Inline functions are functions where the call is made to inline functions"

Comment: Following link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514413/objective-c-inline-function-symbol-not-found/3573500#3573500.

Comment: @vikingosegundo what is recursion  ? i want example of tinline function calling ? can u give me ?

Comment: thanx @Simon i want the same things ...thanx a lot.

Comment: your explanation is recursive. It explains inline-functions by using inline-function. as ur recursion has no simple base case, it is also a infinite loop. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion Recursion is a base pattern in mathematics and computer sience.

Comment: If you're talking about closures (a.k.a: "Blocks" in Cocoa terms), take a look at the [Cocoa Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Block.html) document. Otherwise, you need to explain in clear terms what you're attempting to do.

Comment: The reason why you are being downvoted and this question will likely be closed is because it lacks complete sentences, a clear explanation of need, any kind of an example or code fragment of what you tried, and a phrasing reminiscent of a typical MySpace post.   Please read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since Objective-C is based on C, you can:

```
inline void myf() {int a; a=1;}
```

Objective-C does not support "inline" methods a la C++.

Comment: You can use .mm file in objective C (++). which allow you to write inline functions.