# Any performance gain/loss with having several function calls rather than a single large one?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently making a game for the iPad and iPhone using cocos2d, Box2D and Objective-C.

A lot of stuff is happening every update, and a lot has to be resolved.

I recently refactored a lot of my code to several small methods, instead of having hundreds of lines of code inside the same method.

Is there any performance loss doing this?
Will fewer method calls increase performance?

Comment: As you have done the refactoring - what does your timing tell you?

Comment: See my performance post to learn just how much an Objective-C message send costs, and how that compares to in relation to other tasks: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/depth-ios-cocos2d-performance-analysis-test-project/

Comment: If you're worrying about the number of method calls rather than the sizes of your textures and things like that, I think you're in a good place :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each function call results in a constant-time (`O(1)`) delay because of the stack frame adjustments and branching. However, you won't feel that delay unless the calls are made inside a time-critical loop a million times.

The best approach would be, I think, writing the cleanest code possible and *then* optimizing it -- with the help of a profiler -- as needed.

You may also want to check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4816703/252687 Inline functions may reduce the aforementioned overhead a bit without compromising the modularity.

Comment: +1 I once made a lotto simulator which would loop millions of times and I coded it once calling different methods in the loop and other times as one big code block. The one big code block proved faster, so this "However, you won't feel that delay unless the calls are made inside a time-critical loop a million times." is spot on. :)

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is a performance decline with more method calls. However that is not a reason to use fewer, that would be pre-mature optimization at the expense of cleaner code.

Personally I go for the cleanest most clear code, let the compiler optimize and in the end profile for the real bottlenecks.

I was once hired on the basis of an answer to single question, that was I would profile before optimizing. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have seen cases where multiple smaller functions resulted in significantly better-performing code, since the compiler was better able to optimize registers.  Highly dependent on the compiler and style of programming, though.

But in general, on modern systems (other than really low-level microprocessors) optimizing performance at this level is counter-productive.  Better to well-structure the code (which generally implies a fair number of subroutines) so that it's more reliable, easier to maintain, and easier to spot and fix more global performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

After the compiler optimizes your code, you probably won't notice any reliable performance difference, unless you are trying to use method dispatches inside the inner loops of a CPU intensive computation routine, such as DSP or pixel level image processing.