# iPhone:- Using inline function:- shows error when using Debug configuration

Tags: iphone, struct, inline

when i am using Simulator-> release configuration the code is running ok. but if i use Simulator -> Debug configuration is giving me following error

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_AGTileInfoEqualToAGTile", referenced from:
      -[TiledScrollView loadTileAtPoint:] in TiledScrollView.o
  "_AGTileInfoMake", referenced from:
      -[TiledScrollView loadTilesIfNeeded] in TiledScrollView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

***Here is the code***

```
typedef struct 
{
    NSString *dataSet;
    NSInteger level;
    NSInteger x;
    NSInteger y;


}AGTileInfo;


/* Make a AGTileInfo  */
inline AGTileInfo AGTileInfoMake(NSString *dataSet, NSInteger level, NSInteger x, NSInteger y);

inline AGTileInfo
AGTileInfoMake(NSString *dataSet, NSInteger level, NSInteger x, NSInteger y)
{
    AGTileInfo tInfo;   tInfo.dataSet = dataSet;    tInfo.level = level;    tInfo.x = x;    tInfo.y = y;    return tInfo;
}



inline bool AGTileInfoEqualToAGTile(AGTileInfo info1, AGTileInfo info2);

inline bool
AGTileInfoEqualToAGTile(AGTileInfo info1, AGTileInfo info2)
{
    return [info1.dataSet isEqualToString:info2.dataSet] && (info1.level==info2.level) && (info1.x == info2.x) && (info1.y == info2.y) ;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried compiling without the "inline" clause?

Have a look at this:
[Objective C: Inline function - symbol not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514413/objective-c-inline-function-symbol-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to xj1200. His link was really helpful. All i did was add "static" modifier before inline. Here is the new code and it is working fine.

```
static inline AGTileInfo AGTileInfoMake(NSString *dataSet, NSInteger level, NSInteger x, NSInteger y);

static inline AGTileInfo
AGTileInfoMake(NSString *dataSet, NSInteger level, NSInteger x, NSInteger y)
{
    AGTileInfo tInfo;   tInfo.dataSet = dataSet;    tInfo.level = level;    tInfo.x = x;    tInfo.y = y;    return tInfo;
}


static inline bool AGTileInfoEqualToAGTile(AGTileInfo info1, AGTileInfo info2);

static inline bool
AGTileInfoEqualToAGTile(AGTileInfo info1, AGTileInfo info2)
{
    return [info1.dataSet isEqualToString:info2.dataSet] && (info1.level==info2.level) && (info1.x == info2.x) && (info1.y == info2.y) ;
}
```