# gmp-chudnovsky.c and xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, gmp

when I try to compile and run the gmp-chudnovsky.c file found [here](http://gmplib.org/pi-with-gmp.html) with xcode the following errors appear:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fac_clear", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_fac_compact", referenced from:
      _fac_remove_gcd in main.o
  "_fac_init", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_fac_mul", referenced from:
      _bs in main.o
  "_fac_mul_bp", referenced from:
      _bs in main.o
  "_fac_resize", referenced from:
      _fac_remove_gcd in main.o
  "_fac_set_bp", referenced from:
      _bs in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know the [gmp library](http://gmplib.org/) is installed correctly as I have another xcode project linking to it that is compiling correctly. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Forgot to say I have added paths to the header file and library for GMP as well as add the -lgmp flag under Other Linker Flags

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514413/objective-c-inline-function-symbol-not-found).

I think xcode runs in a Debug configuration first, where no optimization is performed and no inlining is carried out. This means any `inline` function must also be made `static`.